# How to create better dots in continued fraction

Tags: math-mode, formatting, punctuation

Consider

```
 $$\left( a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m \right) \mapsto a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{\cdots + \frac{1}{a_m}}}$$
```

I want to change the cdots into three dots like the following

> dot
>  space dot 
>  space space dot

(Can't find the words to describe this in English.)

Question: Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: The word is probably 'diagonal'.

Comment: What do you mean with "magnified of course"?

Comment: Removed that to prevent Babylonian type of comms. ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `\ddots` for diagonal dots (see §3.12. "Punctuation" in [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf)).
2. Also consider to use `\cfrac` for continued fractions (see §5.4. "Continued fractions" in [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% For \cfrac in the second example

\begin{document}

\[% Here I've just changed the second occurence of \cdots to \vdots
\left( a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m \right) \mapsto a_1 + \frac{1}{a_2 + \frac{1}{\ddots \, + \frac{1}{a_m}}}
\]

\[% \cfrac instead of \frac . This looks much better!
\left( a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m \right) \mapsto a_1 + \cfrac{1}{a_2 + \cfrac{1}{\ddots \, + \cfrac{1}{a_m}}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Equations with diagonal dots]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\left( a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m \right) \mapsto a_1 
   + \dfrac{1}{a_2 
   + \dfrac{1}{\mkern10mu\raisebox{-0.25\height}{$\ddots$} 
   + \dfrac{1}{a_m}}} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

- `\dfrac` is the same as `displaystyle\frac`
- `\mkern` reserves space in math units (1mu=1/18 em)
- `\raisebox` is self explanatory